# Can't dismiss presented view controller through React Native

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, reactjs, react-native

I am doing a hybrid implementation of react-native. I am presenting the React View Controller like so:

```
self.vc = [[ContactForm alloc] init];
self.vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
UIViewController *root = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].rootViewController;
[root presentViewController:self.vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

On an action on the react-native page, I need to dismiss this view controller that I presented, through an exported method. I try to do it like so:

```
@objc(dismissContactForm)
func dismissContactForm() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

It doesn't dismiss, and the view controller stays put. I added the `DispatchQueue` because when the control comes back to the native app, it comes through a background thread.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I did not understand how and where to write and call @objc(dismissContactForm)? please elaborate

Comment: can you share how to achieve this? I stuck here too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. Using React Native's `NativeModules`, a new instance of the class is created every time it's called. For now, I have used the window's root view controller to present and dismiss the view controller to get the instance of the presented controller but the callback blocks `RCTResponseSenderBlock` could also be used.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the code which was used to post a notification callback from react native to ObjectiveC for dismissing a view controller?